# Console log with if, strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, if-statement, console.log

I'm trying to leanr some javascript, however I can't quite answer why:

```
var a = 'xyz';
console.log('Example: ' + (a === 'xyz') ? 'A' : 'B');
```

Gives me back 'A' rather than Example: A. However when I put the whole if like that:

```
var a = 'xyz';
console.log('Example: ' + ((a === 'xyz') ? 'A' : 'B'));
```

It works flawlessly. Does that mean the first one puts the 'Example: ' string in a logical + with this if?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not an `if` statement, it's a ternary operator.

But fundamentally, yes, what's happening is that first this part is evaluted:

```
(a === 'xyz')
```

...and becomes `true` or `false`. Then this is done (let's assume `true`):

```
'Example: ' + true
```

...resulting in:

```
'Example: true'
```

...then this is done:

```
'Example: true' ? 'A' : 'B'
```

...which gives us `'A'` because the string isn't blank, and so it's truthy.

This is because `+` has a higher precedence than the ternary (`? :`).

Comment: Pretty complete answer +1.

Comment: very good answer. definitly true about the first line of code. when thr triple equal sign is used, it is looking to evaluate a bool value. Therefore, its looking for `(a === true)` or `(a === false)`. in this case, a `==` should be used.

Comment: @Mic1780: The result is a boolean either way. `==` just adds type coercion. In the OP's example, there's no difference whatsoever between using `==` and `===` as both `a` and `'xyz'` are strings. *"Therefore, its looking for `(a === true)` or `(a === false)`"* No, that comparison is never being done.

Comment: @Mic1780, no, `===` is the correct comparison. However, it doesn't really matter, because both `String + true` and `String + false` are true as long as `String` is not an empty string.

Comment: @DerekHenderson I see what you mean now after looking it up. The === evaluated the type and the value as the == does only the value. My mistake.

Comment: Thank you all guys for all the answers. I'm satisfied now : )

Answer (score 3):

Exactly, as you can see `+` has higher precedence than `?`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

So in your first expression string concatenation with the boolean value `(a === 'xyz')` gets executed first, the non empty string is then evaluated as a boolean `true` and 'A' is the final output.

In the second expression parenthesis force the `?` operator to be executed before `+`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set off `(a === 'xyz') ? 'A' : 'B'` with parentheses, the JS engine gives precedence to the `+` operator and interprets your truthy test as `'Example: ' + (a === 'xyz')`, thus returning A.

It would return A even if the equality test were false, because a string concatenated with either `true` or `false` is still true.